# How to raise an event inside a UserControl to handle it outside, in another project?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, user-controls, controls

I come after this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076902/how-can-i-make-the-inner-controls-dont-cover-the-main-controls-events). in my `CustomControl` I want to handle all inner controls' `MouseClick` events for example, then raise an event for the customControl, So I can handle it in every project that I use the control.

```
private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var control in Controls)
    {
        ((Control)control).MouseClick += UserControl1_Click;

    }
}

private void UserControl1_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // here I want to raise a MouseClick event for UserControl1?
}
```

How can I solve this problem? ( I think it maybe is like when we catch an exception then throw it again to somewhere else catch it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void UserControl1_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Raise MouseClick event for this control
    base.OnMouseClick(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
Public Event MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)

Private Sub UserControl1_Click (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    RaiseEvent MouseClick(sender, e)
End Sub
```

And then outside handle the `MouseClick` event. (I put the code in Vb.Net because you tagged it in your question, but is easily to convert it).