# Pass through click event to control underneath

Tags: c#

I looked at this question and though it would help but the WndProc does not fire

[Pass-through mouse events to parent control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547172/pass-through-mouse-events-to-parent-control)

So I have a game board, which is a user control with a Picture box.  During the mouseClick event I do a hit test to determine what part of the board was click and put a piece in a relative area.  I then create one of the game pieces and animate it from the hosting form edge to the proper place on the board.  So game piece is not a child of game board

That is all working fine.  However if the user clicks on a game piece, the mouseClick for the board underneath doesn't raise an event.  I sort of get that, like a button under a button.

My question is can I "pass through" the click event of the game piece so only the board is "clickable"

```
public enum PieceColor
{
    Blue=0,
    Yellow,
    Red,
    Green
}

public class GamePiece : PictureBox
{
    PieceColor _color;
    public PieceColor Color {
        get {

            return _color;
        }
        set
        {
            _color = value;

            if (_color == PieceColor.Blue)
                this.Image = global::GameEntities.Properties.Resources.pieceBlue;
        }
    }


    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
        const int HTTRANSPARENT = (-1);

        if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST) //<-- this never fires
        {
            m.Result = (IntPtr)HTTRANSPARENT;
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine and it worked well when I tested it, passing the MouseDown event to the form.  Hard to guess why you are having this problem.

Comment: thanks I will have to look at it again tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make your control transparent for mouse click events, you can pass all the click events to the parent control appropriate method. So, first create an interface that will declare `HandleMouseClick` method.

```
interface IMouseClickable
{
   void HandleMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e);
}
```

Apply this interface to the parent `Control`, so that you can pass this `Control` to `GamePiece`. It could be done via the constructor and you can immedietly register parent `HandleMouseClick` to the `GamePiece`.

```
...
public GamePiece(IMouseClickable parent)
{
   MouseClick += parent.HandleMouseClick;
}
...
```

Comment: Interesting solution, I wonder if I can just pass new MouseEventHandler(game_MouseClick), without the additional interface.  Will try later.

Comment: In the args passed, the coordinates of the mouse click location are relative to the control. So will this not just pass that through but with the coordinates then being incorrect?