# Add click to control inside a panel

Tags: vb.net, panel

Morning,

I am trying to add a click event for the controls that i add into my Panel dynamically. The control i add is a custom class that i have created called 'Slide'.

Here is the code where i build the Slide class that will be added to the panel:

```
        Dim thisControl As New Slide()
        With thisControl
            .Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Left
            .Thumbnail.Image = ThisSlide
            .Thumbnail.BackColor = Color.Transparent

            .Caption.Text = "Slide" & radSlides.SelectedIndex
            .Ordinal = pnlScheduledSlides.Controls.Count.ToString
            .Duration = Conversion.Int(20)
            .Content = pContent
        End With
```

Then I add 'thisControl' to the panel:

```
pnlScheduledSlides.Controls.Add(thisControl)
```

I am wanted to be able to click on a Slide inside the panel so that i can add some functionality to be able to add/remove the slide.

Answer (score 0):

You need a dinamic event handler

```
Addhandler thisControl.Click, AddressOf  your_dinamic_click
```

Where your_dinamic_click is something like this:

```
Private sub your_dinamic_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

I'm supposing that your Slide control raises a "click" event

Comment: I have added the code and the event doesn't get fired?

Comment: of course, this code is for consume the click event. Your custom class has to raise it

Comment: How do i raise this in my custom class

Comment: You Slide() class, I suppose its a usercontrol. I has a click event, by default. But, maybe you have other controls on it, and you can reach the "empty area" of you control. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940270/click-event-is-not-firing-when-i-click-a-control-in-dynamic-usercontrol

Comment: My Slide class does not have a click event?

Comment: I don't know anything about your class. If its a windows.forms.control, it has that event. But, there are more controls on it? Show that class