# Handling UserControl events dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, mouseevent

Initially i was having a picture box which can be moved on the form by user from one place to another.
I have handled the events for the picture box and it was moving perfectly.

But now user wants to display a text below the picture. So I thought to create a custom control dynamically and add that picture box and a label control inside the user control.

I also set the dock properties of controls to TOP and Bottom. Now my user control is completely covered with the sub controls.

After that i want to handle the mouse events for the user control. But unfortunately that is not working for me.

As per my understanding, now i cannot access the user control instead i am having access to sub controls in user control, so the mouse events for user control are not working.

Correct me if am wrong, and provide any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the mouse event like `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` occurs only when the mouse is doing something on the specific control. the best offer i can give you is to catch each mouse event in the controls and call a method on the `userControl`

```
  public UserControl1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.UserControl1_MouseDown);
     this.comboBox1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.comboBox1_MouseDown);
  }

  private void UserControl1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
      UCMouseDown();
  }

  private void UserControl1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
      UCMouseDown();
  }

  private void comboBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
      UCMouseDown();
  }

  private void UCMouseDown()
  {
      // Your code
  }
```

Comment: I have to recalculate the coordinates and position the User control accordingly. But if i handle the events for sub controls i will be getting the coordinates relative to User Control and not relative to Form. In that case coordinates will not be calculated properly.

Comment: Hey that worked. I should have tried it myself. But for this solution i have to handle the events for both my sub controls. What if i have more than 10 controls? Will look forward to get a global approach for this.

Comment: @Lokesh there is a global approach, but you aren't going to like it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547172/pass-through-mouse-events-to-parent-control