# Scrollable panelcontrol with groupboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got a scrollable panelcontrol with multiple groupboxes, but when my mouse is within a groupbox, the scrolling does not work for my complete site, only, when i leave the groupboxes.

Is there a solution for it, so, that I can scroll, even my mouse is in a groupbox?

Comment: There are a few answers documenting how to make a control pass mouse events to its parent. Here is one example that I've used myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547172/pass-through-mouse-events-to-parent-control

Comment: OK, thank you. Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The panel should contain focus (itself or one of its children), then the auto-srcoll feature will work.

The problem which you have with `GroupBox` is clicking on it doesn't activate the control, same as `Label` or `PictureBox` or `Panel` itself.

As a simple workaround you can handle `Click` event of `Panel` or any other control which you want to make auto-scroll work and set it as `ActiveControl` of `Form`:

```
private void control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ActiveControl = (Control)sender;
}
```

You can do it for the `Panel` to enable auto-scroll when you click on an empty area of the panel, or if you want clicking on your `GroupBox` or `Label` case auto-scroll work, you can do the same for them.